# Can I integrate many sources into one RSS reader?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss, atom-feed

I'm looking to integrate a bunch of RSS/ATOM sources into a feed for our intranet.  This is outside my usual realm of work so I've had very limited exposure to this.

I'd like to integrate all the feeds into a single reader such that all the news items are in chronological release order.

Is this doable?  Do I need a special component?  Or can I make the ASP.NET integrated components do all this simply enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the classes in the [`System.ServiceModel.Syndication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx) namespace to read, write, and merge RSS feeds.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just checking this out now

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to create a feed that merges multiple feeds.

Comment: I was just pondering a similar idea using Google Reader to subscribe to all the feeds and then just subscribing to the reader actually.

Comment: Yeah, that would work too.  Pipes gives you more control if you wanted to do any processing on those feeds before generating your aggregate feed.